# Trigonometric Cost Function

Tags: microeconomics, nonexpert, cost-functions

I've been reading on producer theory and came up with a ridiculous question. Has anyone tried to model costs with a trigonometric function? would it work with the assumptions we need? Thanks!

Comment: "*would it work with the assumptions we need?*" What exactly are this needed assumptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a long tradition of using flexible functional forms for cost, utility or production functions. This can be done using a (low) order series expansion. Usually, these are Taylor expansions. For example the translog is a second order polynomial in log prices.

Of course, one could also use a Fourier expansion, which would give a function in terms of cosine and sine functions.

See for example the appendix of [Griffin, Montgomery, Rister,(1987) "Selecting Functional Form In Production Function Analysis," Western Journal of Agricultural Economics](https://ideas.repec.org/a/ags/wjagec/32240.html)